# How to use tool tip in prime ng dynamic data table for Angular 4

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng datatable with Angular 4,having dynamic rows. how I can show a tooltip whenever a user hovers over a row in my primeng datatable? Also, the tooltip needs to display a created and updated date coming from the API server.Each row having diffrent dates.While mouse over a row it should show the created and updated dates of particular row.I cannot find any solutions .Am using primeng latest version with Angular

My datatable is like..

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="Slist" styleClass="myTable" reorderableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true" columnResizeMode="expand" 
selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedResource" [responsive]="true" [rows]="8" [paginator]="true" scrollHeight="300px">
<p-header>STUDENTS DETAILS</p-header>
<p-header>
    <div style="text-align:left">
        <p-multiSelect [options]="columnOptions" [(ngModel)]="cols"></p-multiSelect>
    </div>
</p-header>
<p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" 
[header]="col.header" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" [editable]="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" filterPlaceholder="Search"></p-column>
<p-footer>
</p-footer>
</p-dataTable>
```

Many Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with primefaces and primefaces-extensions. primeng = angular, primefaces and extensions = jsf.

Comment: thanks for your answer!